# Efficient way to search object from list of object in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a list which contains more than 75 thousand object. To search item from list currently I am using following code.

```
from nd in this.m_ListNodes
where
   nd.Label == SearchValue.ToString()
   select
   nd;
```

Is this code is efficient?

Comment: @Marco: the OP has asked a total of 5 questions (this one included) with quite few answers on them. It *could* be that there have not been good enough answers yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How often do you need to search the same list? If you're only searching once, you might as well do a straight linear search - although you can make your current code slightly more efficient by calling `SearchValue.ToString()` *once* before the query.

If you're going to perform this search on the same list multiple times, you should either build a `Lookup` or a `Dictionary`:

```
var lookup = m_ListNodes.ToLookup(nd => nd.Label);
```

or

```
var dictionary = m_ListNodes.ToDictionary(nd => nd.Label);
```

Use a dictionary if there's exactly one entry per label; use a lookup if there may be multiple matches.

To *use* these, for a lookup:

```
var results = lookup[SearchValue.ToString()];
// results will now contain all the matching results
```

or for a dictionary:

```
WhateverType result;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(SearchValue.ToString(), out result))
{
    // Result found, stored in the result variable
}
else
{
    // No such item
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. It would be better if you used a Dictionary or a HashSet with the label as the key. In your case a Dictionary is the better choice:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IList<Item>>();

// somehow fill dictionary

IList<Item> result;
if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(SearchValue.ToString(), out result)
{
    // if you need an empty list 
    // instead of null, if the SearchValue isn't in the dictionary
    result = new List<Item>(); 
}

// result contains all items that have the key SearchValue
```

Comment: A `HashSet` wouldn't work, if he's trying to find the item. A dictionary will work if there's only a single match, but fail if multiple items have the same label.

Comment: I try with dictionary still it takes time. The code is :        from nd in this.m_NodeDict
                              where
                              nd.Key == SearchValue.ToString()
                              select
                              nd.Value;

Comment: @JonSkeet: The Dictionary fails only, if you are using it wrong. If there are several items with the same label, use a `Dictionary<string, IList<Item>>`. Problem solved.

Comment: @Daniel: At that point, why not just use a `Lookup`? I'd rather reuse  code that's already written than write it myself :) I guess my point was mostly that you ought to distinguish between the two cases (unique label or not).